# Xamarin.Forms Failed to resolve assembly stateless error

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

After upgrading to the latest version of Xamarin.Forms (2.3.3.175) my iOS project throws the compilation error

Failed to resolve assembly: 'Stateless, Version=2.5.53.0, Culture=neutral, ...' (MT2002) in File MTOUCH and Path MTOUCH

The shared code is in a PCL library targeting PCL 4.5 - Profile78

So far Google search hasn't returned anything.

Anyone encounter this yet? Appreciate any help in resolving this.

I am using Xamarin Studio Community Edition version 6.1.2 (Build 44)

Comment: Do you have the latest Developer Tools from XCode installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely using couchbase lite. Stateless is an assembly required by couchbase lite. It seems it cannot be resolved if used in a pcl project. You can read something about this problem [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-lite-for-xamarin-pcl-project/4295/9). A couchbase developer states that

> The strategy has changed since then. We won't be supporting PCL but instead we aim to support .NET Standard 2.0 when it is ready.

Hope this helps.

Comment: holly molly!! how did you figure that out? You are absolutely right! I *AM* trying to use CouchbaseLite in a PCL project. The PCL project compiled without errors but the iOS project threw the compilation error leading me to erroneously suspect a recent update to Xamarin.Forms package for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

`Xamarin.Forms` has NO dependency on an assembly named `Stateless` of any sort. Check your dependencies, and your dependencies dependencies...